# Python regular expressions with complex characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem with regular expression in a python code. I'm trying to parse a file whose structure is the following:

```
------------
some complex text
abcd
more text
-----------
```

With several boxes with the same pattern.
I want to get only the boxes that contain the 'abcd' string. I managed to find all the occurrences of the 'abcd' string but I can't get all the text between the ---. I have tried to build up a toy string but i can't make it work. Code below:

```
import re
text = ('-----\nsajnpajnfpiajbpiabvpier abcd fgdspoj\n------' +
        '-----\nsajnpajnfpiajbpiabvpierfgdspoj\n------')
data = re.findall(r"---(.*?)abcd(.*?)---", text)
```

Any help is appreciated
EDIT: I modified the text example to make it more realistic

Comment: would `-+[\s\S]+abcd[\s\S]+?-+` work?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mWiE5D/2 or https://regex101.com/r/mWiE5D/3

Comment: uhm it does in the context of the small test but it doesn't isolate the specific subsection I want, I'll modify the test to make it more similar to what I look for

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/mWiE5D/4

Comment: Thanks Wiktor I didn't know that website, I'll look into it

Comment: Also, check https://regex101.com/r/mWiE5D/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need regex to find a simple string. This might be a simplification of what you're looking for:

```
s="""
some complex text
abcd
more text
-----------
some complex text
aoecd
more text
-----------
some complex text
abcd
more text
"""
# split the strings and add only those that contain "abcd"
result = [d for d in s.split("-----------") if "abcd" in d]
for r in result:
    print(r)
# result:
# some complex text
# abcd
# more text
# 
# some complex text
# abcd
# more text
```

As you can see, we split the string when `"-----------"` appears and then we evaluate if the substring "abcd" is contain in each of the strings, and we keep the strings that passed this condition.

Comment: I was trying to use regex because I thought it would be easier (although I'm not really good with it) but thinking again your solution is in fact easier and works nicely with my real data (and I understand it better). I'll think about it for a bit before accepting an answer

Comment: Take your time. The important thing it's that the solution works well in your situation. ;)